# Adding multi-plot axes

Tags: r

In order to generate a layout with multiple plots, I have the following code with some dummy plots:

```
jpeg("/path/to/file",height=10000,width=5000)
plot.new()
par(mar=c(2,2,1,1), oma=c(2,4,0,0), xpd=NA)

for (i in 1:10) {

    par(mar=c(2,2,1,1),fig=c(0, 0.5, (10-i)/10, (11-i)/10), new=T)    
    matplot(rnorm(20)*sample(100,1),                                          
        col="blue",axes=F,type="l",lwd=10, xlab="",ylab="")

    par(mar=c(2,2,1,1),fig=c(0.5, 1, (10-i)/10, (11-i)/10), new=T)    
    matplot(rnorm(20)*sample(100,1),                                          
        col="red",axes=F,type="l",lwd=10, xlab="",ylab="")    
}
dev.off()
```

I want to add a vertical line/axis on the far LHS and the far RHS that span all 10 plots in a column. Since I will use this line as an axis, I need to be able to add ticks and labels.

Comment: How do you want the tick labels to look? For example, the sample plot derived from your code has 2 columns of plots. are the tick labels for the 2nd column of plots a continuation of the tick labels of the 1st column? e.g., if the first column's tick labels are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, do you want the 2nd column's tick labels to be 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, or do you want 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 again.

Comment: @X.He the former i.e. 1 to 5 on one column and continuation from 6 to 10 on second column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could draw axis by `?axis` or `?Axis`. To span your axis on multiple plots you have to reset the *usr* coordinates.

Please find a base graphics solution below:

```
## store number of rows
nRow <- 10

## your example code 
## (only the number "10" is replaced by nRow and oma is adapted)
plot.new()

par(mar=c(2, 2, 1, 1), oma=c(2, 4, 0, 4), xpd=NA)

for (i in 1:nRow) {

    par(mar=c(2, 2, 1, 1), fig=c(0, 0.5, (nRow-i)/nRow, ((nRow+1)-i)/nRow), new=TRUE)    
    matplot(rnorm(20)*sample(100, 1),                                          
            col="blue", axes=F, type="l", lwd=10, xlab="", ylab="")

    par(mar=c(2, 2, 1, 1), fig=c(0.5, 1, (nRow-i)/nRow, ((nRow+1)-i)/nRow), new=TRUE)
    matplot(rnorm(20)*sample(100, 1),                                          
            col="red", axes=F, type="l", lwd=10, xlab="", ylab="")    
}

## define new user coordinates
usr <- c(0, 1, 0, 1) ## x1, x2, y1, y2

## calculate tick positons
## in general: (usr[3]+(diff(usr[3:4])/(nRow-1))*0:(nRow-1))
## but our usecase is much easier:
ticksAt <- 1/(nRow-1)*0:(nRow-1)

## choose left column and reset user plotting area (usr)
par(mar=c(2, 2, 1, 1), fig=c(0, 0.5, 0, 1), usr=usr, new=TRUE)
## draw axis; see ?Axis for details
Axis(side=2, at=ticksAt, labels=as.character(1:(nRow)), line=0.5)

## choose right column and reset user plotting area (usr, not needed because already done)
par(mar=c(2, 2, 1, 1), fig=c(0.5, 1, 0, 1), usr=usr, new=TRUE)
## draw axis; see ?Axis for details
Axis(side=4, at=ticksAt, labels=as.character((nRow+1):(2*nRow)), line=0.5)
```

Comment: For some reason the ticks on the LH axis are much smaller than the ones on the RH axis

Comment: @user1202664: Works for me like expected (all ticks are equally sized).

Answer (score 0):

You could make one overall plot of the entire device, add the axes there, then use the `subplot` function (TeachingDemos package) to do the plots within the large plot.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to use only base packages atm with my existing code.